# ImageMagick number of supported formats value = 0

Tags: php, imagemagick

I spent all the day looking to solve this problem. I install ImageMagick and copy the files from coders modules to `apache/bin` and in `c:/windows/system`. I add the extension in `php.ini`. I copy `php_imagick.dll` in `php/ext`
but the problem still!